# Google Cloud : check disk space usage

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-storage

How to check the used disk space of Google Persistent Disk without looking into each of them?

[image]

Comment: This feature currently is not available. As such, you can file a feature request through [this link](https://code.google.com/p/google-compute-engine/issues/list).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't see it in the disk preview as Faizan said, But you could Use Google StackDriver Monitoring tool to get a nice preview of your instances status.

Answer (score 13):

The workaround with snapshot size will work in the console.

For more precise (and quicker) detailed overview you can SSH into your instance and do:

```
sudo df -h
```

The response you get will look similar to this:

```
YOURUSERNAME@YOURINSTANCENAME:~$ sudo df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1       9.8G  9.3G     0 100% /
udev             10M     0   10M   0% /dev
tmpfs           743M   81M  663M  11% /run
tmpfs           1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sdb        197G   60M  197G   1% /mnt/new_disk
```

Entries starting with /dev/ under 'Filesystem' are your disks.

Comment: the question states `without looking into each of them`

Answer (score 8):

I use a simple workaround for this.

Create a snapshot of your persistent disk, and look at the snapshot size:

[image]

Comment: Good workaround, too bad it takes so long though

Comment: snapshot size is 'compressed' disk size, not real disk usage size

Answer (score 1):

Just install Monitoring Agents in https://console.cloud.google.com/monitoring/dashboards/resourceList/gce_instance
then check the dashboard

Answer (score 0):

In your terminal use this command to detect files size and which directory is more bulky:

```
ncdu /
```